# MySQL update takes too long when updating data from other table

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with my code and I don't know why update won't work I would be thankful if someone can help me here. The error says **Lost connection to MySql server during query**. I only have **3000 results** when selecting the data of **table2 where year is 2019**, I don't know what's taking time to update the column of **table1** (maybe I have error in my query?)

Here is my query:

```
UPDATE `db_a`.`table1`  
INNER JOIN `db_a`.`table2` ON `table2`.`table2_id` = `table1`.`table1_id`  
SET `table1`.`table1_number` = `table2`.`table2_number`
WHERE `table1`.`year` = 2019;
```

I just wanted to update the the column of **table1_number** and set the data to the value of **table2_number**.

Comment: you must have 2 indexes, one of table1.year and one on table2.table2_id

Comment: Put an `EXPLAIN` in front of your query and see what MySQL comes back with. It will tell you why your `UPDATE` is slow.

Comment: @BerndBuffen What to you mean? Can you explain it more because I'm confused. I have 2 indexes already on table 1 and table 2 which is the id of both table that is being used in joining them. I only wanted to update the data of table1_number and set the value of table2_number to it where the year of table1 is equal to 2019.

Comment: ..., and for the **WHERE `table1`.`year` = 2019;** you must have a index on table1,year . also post the result of the **EXPLAIN**